# VREP: Hide emission radius during simulation

Tags: lua, simulation

Is there a way to avoid the simulator from drawing the emission radius of a transceiver during simulation in VREP? Because with two transceivers moving on two quadcopters the simulation is already lagging and since I'm planning to use at least 5-6 of them, that makes the simulator really unusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after getting familiar with the LUA scripts I found out how to do it.

To enable/disable the visualization of the emission radius you have to use the API function [*simSetBooleanParameter()*](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/en/apiFunctions.htm#simSetBooleanParameter) proposed in the other answer. In particular **in the LUA script** of the transceiver, after the initialization you'll need the following instruction:

```
simSetBooleanParameter(sim_boolparam_force_show_wireless_emission,false)
```

Or if you don't ever want to turn on the visualization again just delete all the occurences *simSetBool* related to the *[force_show_wireless_emission](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/en/apiConstants.htm#booleanParameters)* parameter in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it helps, but you can disable visualization as a whole. I am copying and pasting from the forum thread (http://www.forum.coppeliarobotics.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=685):

- **Disable visualization**. Check out the model Models/other/fast
  simulation mode.ttm, or the API function
  [simSetBooleanParameter](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/helpFiles/en/apiFunctions.htm#simSetBooleanParameter)(sim_boolparam_display_enabled,false).
- **Disable dynamics**. You can do this in the dynamics general settings.
  You can also individually disable models for dynamics simulation.
  Select the model, then open the model properties dialog. Check Model
  is static and Model is not respondable.

Comment: Unfortunately the simSetBooleanParameter disables the whole visualization, but your hint gave me the right direction! I'll post the answer, thanks!